# Locating element after finding by text in selenium python

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, element

I am trying to locate the position of element where a text i looked for was found, on the page where it could appear from position 1-10 and they get change to different positions randomly after the countdown.
Take for example:
My search was "CHE", it could appear anywhere from position 1-10 in the xpath `//div[@class="gb-widget_match-list ext-widget_match-list"]` inside the iframe of the page. "CHE" was found with `driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[contains(text(), "CHE")]').is_displayed()` but i want to make use of python to locate the element and also it odds element so the odd could be clicked.

Here's link to the website: https://www.betking.com/virtuals/v/kings-league
Thank you.

Comment: Share the block of code you have tried.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to click on the Event based on the Teams, below code might help you.

```
driver.implicitly_wait(10)
driver.get("https://www.betking.com/virtuals/v/kings-league")
driver.switch_to.frame(1)
teams = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//div[@class='gb-widget_match-info-teams']")
for team in teams:
    value = team.get_attribute("innerText").replace('\n','')
    if "CHE" in value:
        team.click()
        time.sleep(2)
        break
driver.quit()
```

Update: For navigation through `Arrow` buttons.

```
driver.get("https://www.betking.com/virtuals/v/kings-league")
driver.switch_to.frame(1)
teams = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//div[@class='gb-widget_match-info-teams']")
teams[0].click()
time.sleep(2)
nextarrow = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//span[@class='gb-widget_content-swiper-next']")
while "disabled" not in nextarrow.get_attribute("class"):
    nextarrow.click()
    time.sleep(1)
```

Update-2:

```
driver.get("https://www.betking.com/virtuals/v/kings-league")
driver.switch_to.frame(1)
next = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//span[@class='gb-widget_content-swiper-next']")
for i in range(3):
    next.click()
    time.sleep(1)

teams = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//div[contains(@class,'swiper-slide-active')]/div")
for team in teams:
    time.sleep(1)
    value = team.find_element_by_xpath(".//div[@class='gb-widget_match-info-teams']").get_attribute("innerText").replace('\n','')
    if "CHE" in value:
        buttons = team.find_elements_by_tag_name("button")
        # for button in buttons:
        #     print(button.get_attribute("innerText"))
        buttons[0].click()
        time.sleep(2)
        break
driver.quit()
```

Comment: It works. Thank you.
Could you kindly explain this:  value = team.get_attribute("innerText").replace('\n','')
and why you replaced newline with no spacing.

Comment: @Crash_Override - Was more specific about the result `value`. For example without replacement the `value` will be `LIV\n-\nSOU` but with it, it would be `LIV-SOU`. Good to read as well as to understand.

Comment: Yeah understood.
My main aim is to click on the odd directly without clicking on the team `if "CHE" in value:` is `True` . I specifically want to click on the odd on the "Over / Under 1.5" Tab in the iframe
`def switchToOver1_5():
    driver.find_element_by_xpath('//div[@class="swiper-pagination-bullet gb-widget_swiper-pagination-dot ext-widget_swiper-pagination-dot"][3]').click()` .

That is, clicking on either over 1.5 odd or under 1.5 odd without going through clicking the teams and navigating to "Over / Under 1.5" row and then clicking on either of the odds.

Thanks.

Comment: @Crash_Override - But the option `Over/Under 1.5` appears after we click on the Event.

Comment: Quite true, the motive is navigate to `Over / Under 1.5` Tab/Section with xpath `driver.find_element_by_xpath('//div[@class="swiper-pagination-bullet gb-widget_swiper-pagination-dot ext-widget_swiper-pagination-dot"][3]')` and then click on either of the odds associated to the team we want.

Comment: @Crash_Override -  That kind navigation is easier when we click on the `Arrow` button. the code for the same is updated in answer.

Comment: Yes i am aware, Seem you do not understand. Please kindly check out this image https://ibb.co/Vxn3WKX . Where 1 represent the navigation xpath `driver.find_element_by_xpath('//div[@class="swiper-pagination-bullet gb-widget_swiper-pagination-dot ext-widget_swiper-pagination-dot"][3]')` and this  https://ibb.co/sC7ffzt pointing to the odds associated to the match we want. I want to navigate to the `Over / Under 1.5` Tab first and then click on the odds directly without clicking on the team, going to `Over / Under 1.5` row then the odds. 
I hope you understand

Comment: Yes, now I understood. Updated the answer.

Comment: It worked, Thank you. please could you kindly explain this line     `value = team.find_element_by_xpath(".//div[@class='gb-widget_match-info-teams']").get_attribute("innerText").replace('\n','')`. I seem not to understand why you used each item of the list to find another webelement.

Comment: @Crash_Override - We are trying to select the odds based on the team, so first we need to choose the team and then try to access thier options.

Comment: Alright, I'll give a try. What could be the reason an element be found on a browser with it xpath and not on IDE?

Comment: @Crash_Override - Element not found on IDE? I dint get your question.

Comment: I meant Integrated development environment, i was looking up an element on the webpage but it wasn't coming up on IDE(It displays an empty list) but it shows on the browser. I discovered i haven't switched to the iframe where it could be found.
Thank you so much for your time.